# How can I reduce row height in DT datatables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to be able to get 'slimmer' rows when rendering a `DT` datatable (ie decrease that height)

```
options(digits.secs=6)
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00.123'))
library(DT)
datatable(d)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `datatable(d, class="compact")`

Comment: @HubertL the only thing it appears to be doing is removing the nice highlighting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you add the `pageLength=` attribute you can set how many rows to show initially. And by adjusting the `lengthMenu= c()` you can also control the sizes of offered in the drop down, You can also turn search on or off with    `searching =FALSE`

```
   library(DT)
    datatable(d, options=list(
       pageLength = 3,
       lengthMenu = c(2, 12, 18),
       searching= FALSE))%>%

   formatStyle( 0, target= 'row',color = 'black', backgroundColor = 'yellow', fontWeight ='bold', lineHeight='70%')
```

And by using the helper functions you can set the style just as you would in traditional CSS on a webpage. Notice the last one, line-height should adjust the row height.

Edited: I moved all the code together for you to see how it works. Sorry I was not clearer up front. The `%>%`is necessary as is `devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")` version of DT.

Comment: sounds interesting, but was anybody able to reproduce that? =)

Comment: Sorry, I cut and pasted WITHOUT the import part...`options=list()` around the arguments. I have used it and it works. If you cannot get this to work, be sure you installed the `devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT") version`.

Comment: you can include any camelCase modified CSS style for the type this way...

Comment: @sconfluentus Is it possible to adust the height of the header row and filter row similarly?

Comment: @kartik_subbarao that is a very good question, I have not tried it before. Sorry about that one!

Answer (score 4):

I found the above answer didn't work. My simpler solution found via https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html is to use:

```
DT::datatable(df) %>%
DT::formatStyle(names(df),lineHeight='80%')
```

Comment: The only difference in your solution is the use of pipes and the calling of `DT` using `:` .  The `formatStyle()` is accomplished the same way. With properly called `leaflet` the `::` is not needed, but scoping can be an issue depending on the order in which you call packages from your library.